# How to use Azure CloudQueueClient within Web API?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-storage-queues

I have a ASP.NET Web API 2.0 project running in Azure.  The main method is called every minute by 1000s of remote devices.  There seems to be a memory issue.  When the API is started the memory loading is about 40%.  Within 24 hours this creeps up to 80+%, at which time I restart the service and memory drops back to 40% and the cycle begins again.  This is a relatively new problem resulting from increasing numbers of devices connecting.  I guess some threshold has been reached.

The main method that the remote devices are calling basically takes the device data and pushes it onto a Azure Queue via a CloudQueueClient.  Before the memory loading became a problem I was creating a new CloudQueueClient for each call.  When I changed this to a global CloudQueueClient the memory issues seemed to be alleviated somewhat - the time it took to go from 40% - 80% increased by a factor of 10+.  This is why I'm thinking my use of CloudQueueClient and CloudQueue objects might be the issue.

I push the device data using:

```
 var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);
 await queue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(message));
```

Where queueClient is my global CloudQueueClient instance.  As you can see I'm still created an instance of CloudClient on every call.  Should I be reusing an instance of CloudClient for every call.

My question is simply, what is the right way to use CloudQueueClient and CloudQueue within the context of a Web API application?

Note that I distribute the incoming device messages across several queues to relief the loading on each queue so as not to be throttled.

Answer (score 0):

Can't the device send the data directly to the queue instead of using your api as middleman? There is a [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/queue-service-rest-api) available.

Also [this link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/270) may be helpful:

> You can reuse the CloudQueue and CloudQueueClient instances.

Comment: The devices used to deliver directly to the queue but then Microsoft upgraded the queues to require TLS, and the devices only use SSL and cannot be upgraded to support TLS, so I had to write a ‘gateway’ for them.  I’ll see if reusing a global CloudQueue instance helps. Thnx.

Comment: Ok. Bit off topic maybe but did you take a look at [Event Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-what-is-event-hubs) as a replacement for queues? Maybe the devices can directly publish to an event hub.